# Edit>copy/paste implementation with perl / tk

Tags: perl, user-interface, clipboard

I'm using Perl/Tk to build the GUI for an application. I plan on adding an edit menu to it with standard cut, copy, and paste options. Right here is where I realized that I've never actually interacted with the clipboard using perl.

Can anyone give me a link to information about messing with clipboard in perl? Is there a perl module for those kind of functions in specific?

And would I have to modify my code to be platform-specific if I interact with the clipboard since it's part of the host OS, and not part of my application itself?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for [Win32::Clipboard](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-Clipboard/)?

Comment: This looks like it will work nicely for a Windows environment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use Win32::GuiTest qw(:ALL);
use Win32::Clipboard;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my @windows = FindWindowLike( 0, "Total", "" );
die "Could not find Total\n" if not @windows;

SetForegroundWindow( $windows[0] );

&send_keys;

sub send_keys {
my $dir=strftime( '%Y%m%d', localtime(time) );
my $CLIP = Win32::Clipboard();
  $CLIP->Set($dir);
  $CLIP->WaitForChange();
    SendKeys("^V");
#    SendKeys("{ENTER}");
}
```